# How to replace "\" with "\\"

Tags: python

I've a path from `wx.FileDialog (getpath())` shows `"c:\test.jpg"` which doesn't works with opencv `cv.LoadImage()` which needs `"\\"` or `"/"`

So, I've tried to use replace function for example:

```
s.replace("\","\\"[0:2]),s.replace("\\","\\\"[0:2])
```

but none those works.

And, this command `s.replace("\\","/"[0:1])` returns the same path, I don't know why.

Could you help me solve this easy problem.

ps, I'm very new to python

thank you so much. sorry about my grammar

Comment: have you tried `s.replace("\\","/")` forward slashes are compat on win and linux.

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass a string with embedded escapes to a function to have it open correctly...

Answer (score 4):

`\` escapes the next character. To actually get a backslash, you must escape it. Use `\\`:

```
 s.replace("\\","/")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking for `s.replace("\\","/")`

Looking at the docs, and im not a Python programmer but its like so:

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
```

So your do not need the 3rd parameter, but you need new and old obviusly.

```
s.replace("\\","/")
```

the reason we have `\\` as because if we only had `"\"` this means that your escaping a quotation and your `old` parameter gets sent a  `"` that's if python don't trigger and error.

you need to send a Literal backslash like \ so what actually gets sent to the interpreter is a single `\`

you will notice with SO syntax highlighter where the string is being escaped..

```
s.replace("\","\\"[0:2]) #yours                        "
s.replace("\\","/") #mine
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear to me what you want to do with the paths, but there are a number of functions for dealing with them. You may want to use os.path.normpath() which will correct the slashes for whatever platform you are running on.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can use `/` independently from the OS as path separator (as RobertPitt pointed out, you can do this anyway).

But to answer your question, this should work:

```
str.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

Comment: just to let you know in case you don't, Windows and unix both support forward slashes so its best to always standardise paths with a `/`

Comment: @RobertPitt: No, I didn't. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def onOpen(self, event): # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open an Image")
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        __imgpath__ = dlg.GetPath()
        print 'Selected:', dlg.GetPath()
        self.panel_2.LoadImage(cv.LoadImage(__imgpath__))
```

I don't know why, but it works with opencv.

output : "Selected: c:\test.jpg"

I'm sorry I didn't try it out first.